# Config AuthzSVNReposRelativeAccessFile on SubversionEdge

Tags: svn, httpd.conf, subversion-edge, authz

I would like to config access rule per repo on SubversionEdge.

I mean use ***AuthzSVNReposRelativeAccessFile*** = authz directive in httpd.conf to set up access file per repo instead of using one file for all repos.

```
<Location /svn/>   
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath "/opt/csvn/data/repositories"
   SVNReposName "CollabNet Subversion Repository"

  <IfModule deflate_module>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  </IfModule>
  AuthzSVNReposRelativeAccessFile "authz"
  SVNListParentPath On
</Location>
```

But it doesn't work, access rule still using one file for all.
Any folks here have exp on configuring like this, please help. Thanks.